# Object is not iterable: Filtering QuerySet to display latest instance

Tags: python, django, view, model, django-queryset

I am trying to create a filter in a QuerySet using Django that returns the most recent instance that was submitted by the current logged in user.

I so far have the following in my view.py file:

```
def transfer(request):

    title = 'Transfers'

    queryset = Transfer.objects.filter(user=request.user).latest('timestamp')

    context = {
        "title": title,
        "queryset": queryset,
    }

    if request.method == "POST":
        print request.POST

    return render(request, "transfer.html", context)
```

However this returns the error

> TypeError: 'Transfer' object is not iterable

My models.py file looks like this so far:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Transfer(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
```

and my html file is calling the QuerySet in the following way:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <h2>Your Transfers</h2>
    {% if queryset %}
        {% for instance in queryset %}
            <p>Amount: {{ instance.amount }} </p>
            <p>User: {{ instance.user }} </p>
            <p>Date: {{ instance.timestamp }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <h3>You have not made any transfers.</h3>
    {% endif %}

{% endif %}
```

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: You don't have a `user` attribute in your `Transfer` class.  You probably need to alter to `Transfer.objects.filter(username=request.user.username).latest('timestamp')`

Comment: Apologies, I have since changed that model field to: `user = models.ForeignKey(User)`

Comment: Can you update the question accordingly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`latest` returns a single object: the latest one. So you're no longer passing an iterable queryset to the template, but a single instance which naturally you can't iterate.

It's not clear what you want to do here; perhaps you just need to remove the for loop, and just refer to the instance directly. Alternatively, if you do want differing you can iterate over, you might want to remove the `latest` call and just order by reverse timestamp.

Comment: I am trying to display the most recent transfer made by the user that is currently logged in using the following: 
  `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
   <h2>Your Transfers</h2>
   {% if queryset %}
    {% for instance in queryset %}
     <p>Amount: {{ instance.amount }} </p>
     <p>User: {{ instance.user }} </p>
     <p>Date: {{ instance.timestamp }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
   {% else %}
    <h3>You have not made any transfers.</h3>
   {% endif %}

  {% endif %}`

Comment: When I order by reverse timestamp I get the same error: `TypeError: 'Transfer' object is not iterable`

Comment: Can you show the whole view (as an edit to the question)?

Comment: Ah, all of a sudden the error has gone away with your suggestion to change the view to `queryset = Transfer.objects.filter(user=request.user).reverse()[:1]`! However it now shows the oldest instance, I was hoping for it to show the most recent.

Comment: You need `.order_by('-timestamp')`.

Answer (score 2):

Update you query like this

```
ueryset = Transfer.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('timestamp')[count_limit:]
```

[count_limit:] means how many objects from top you want to get. For getting top 5 you can do [:5]
You do not have to add id field, as django automatically add this.

Comment: This returns the following error `global name 'count_limit' is not defined`

Comment: count_limit is just example. it means if you want to get top 5 elements, do it like [5:]

Comment: Oh I see, `queryset = Transfer.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-timestamp')[:1]` works great!